# Gender of words that have a natural gender

Tags: gender

I'm new to Italian, and I'm grappling the concept of gender. For example, the word *scimmia* (monkey) is feminine, but sure there are male monkeys. What do we do if we want to specify a male monkey?

Comment: If your question is only about male monkeys you should perhaps change the title, which is much broader

Comment: Nope, I am using monkey to illustrate my overall questions. But feel free to edit it to be more appropriate

Comment: No way I'm going to change your question if it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would simply refer to them as:

- la scimmia femmina
- la scimmia maschio

If you are talking/writing about monkeys you would just say, il maschio (the male) e la femmina (the female). See the example below:

[Lo strano amoreggiamento dei cebi della Serra da Capivara. 
Femmine che tirano sassate per attirare i maschi: corteggiamento estremo in natura](http://www.greenreport.it/news/aree-protette-e-biodiversita/femmine-che-tirano-sassate-per-attirare-i-maschi-corteggiamento-estremo-in-natura-video/).

Comment: Also it depends on the case, but when addressing "unknown" genders "in general" just using the plural usually works: for one "le scimmie"